# React Native Firebase state undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-elements

I've tried multiple implementations, and I can't seem to get the state to not be undefined. I've tried arrow functions, I've tried binding this inside the onChange event, and nothing seems to work. Can somebody take my codebase and give me some insight as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Button, Text, Input} from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    heading: {
        padding: 20,
    },
});

export default class ContactForm extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
        }
    }

    handleName(e)
    {
        this.setState({name: e.target.value})
        console.log(e.target.value);
    }

    handleEmail(e)
    {
        
    }

    submit(e)
    {
        console.log(this.state.name + " " + this.state.email);
    }

    render() 
    {
    return (
    <View style={styles.heading}>
        <Text h5>Sign up to receive updates/newsletters!</Text>
        <Input placeholder="your name" onChange={this.handleName.bind(this)} />
        <Input placeholder="your email" onChange={this.handleEmail.bind(this)} />
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={this.submit}/>
    </View>
    )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can do it like this there is no need to bind the arrow function with "this".

```
export default class ContactForm extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
        }
    }

    handleName=(e)=>
    {   console.log(e);
        this.setState({name: e})
        
    }

    handleEmail=(e)=>
    {
        this.setState({email: e})
    }

    submit=()=>
    {
        console.log(this.state.name + " " + this.state.email);
    }

    render() 
    {
    return (
    <View style={styles.heading}>
        <Text h5>Sign up to receive updates/newsletters!</Text>
        <Input placeholder="your name" onChangeText ={this.handleName} /> 
        //change onChange to onChangeText 
        <Input placeholder="your email" onChangeText={this.handleEmail} />
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={this.submit}/>
    </View>
    )
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it and it's still undefined. There's no value for e and e is a massive react object.

Comment: Are you using react native Input ?

Comment: React-native-elements, but it inherits all of the native Input functionality.

Comment: I have edit my answer and added a comment please try that solution once

Comment: That's crazy! Every piece of documentation that I get shows that you have to use 'e.target.value' Changing it to `(e)` and using `onChangeText` made it work! Thanks!